# How to programmatically reload ASP.NET page as new session, as if first access to the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, web-applications

I have an ASP.NET web app that uses a single page, but makes some controls invisible and others visible throughout the workflow.  It's a fairly simple application, which is why it just uses one page.

I'm not sure though how to reload the page when a user clicks a cancel button, or when they complete the workflow.  Here's some details about the application workflow...

- The page loads and displays a LoginTable control with a dropdown list with employee names, and a pinpad where a pin number is entered for the selected employee, and a login button.
- On clicking the login button, a postback occurs where the pin is validated, and if valid, the Table control that holds most of the page contents (except the header) gets made invisible, and a new Table control gets made visible depending on the current status (clocked in or out).
- At this point, either the ClockInTable or ClockOutTable control are visible, and the LoginTable control is invisible.  The user can either click a Cancel button, or a Clock In / Out button (with some other things to select if clocking in, like work site and job).

What I want is, when the user either clicks the Cancel, Clock In or Clock Out buttons (after any other processing on postback), for the page to load again with a new session and showing the main LoginTable again just as if the user had restarted the browser and opened the page for the first time.

I've tried using Session.Abandon(), and then in the Global.asax Session_End event, I do 
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");

This doesn't work though; it still just reloads the same view of the page.

How do you reload the page (not refresh the page) as if it were the first access (i.e. not a postback)?

Also, I'm new to ASP.NET, so if I'm misunderstanding how a session works, please let me know.

Comment: Rather than calling `Session.Abandon()`, can you just call `Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Response.Redirect()-ing the user to the same page? That should load the page as if it were a new one. It won't lose the session data though.

Comment: Yes, I tried doing that in the Session_End event, which should be triggered when I call Session.Abandon(), right?

Comment: When you say *should*, have you verified it indeed *is*?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure you can do that the way you describe. However, what you can do is have a flag as a session variable. Call it say `IsFirstComer`. I'm not sure how the workflow of your system goes, but you can have it reset to `true` every time a new user logs in (hasn't started a workflow yet), or has exited a workflow (needs to start all over again), but as soon as te user has started the workflow you set it to `false`. Your controls behaviour can then be controlled through the value of `IsFirstComer`.

Comment: Good idea.  I might use this approach if I can't figure it out otherwise.  +1

Answer (score 0):

Have you write: `if(!this.IsPostback)` in the `Page_Load` method, after that try "`Response.Redirect(page.aspx)`" again.